# If $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and is a unit vector, why is $\sum\limits_{j,k=1}^n |x_j||x_k| < n^2$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, quadratic-forms

This is an excerpt of a larger proof:
[image]

Other pertinent information:

- $A$ is a positive definite $n \times n$ matrix
- The set $C$ is the unit sphere

I don't get the last inequality:

$\gamma \sum \limits_{j,k=1}^n |x_j||x_k| < \gamma n^2$

Why is $\sum \limits_{j,k=1}^n |x_j||x_k| < n^2$?

This looks like it might have something to do with $x$ being in $C$ but the expression in the summation is not the norm for $x$ so I don't see how that is helpful.

Comment: Since $x$ is unit vector, than any component $x_i$ cannot have norm greater than 1, i.e. for any $j$ it holds $|x_j|\leq 1$. The sum involves $n^2$ addends $|x_j||x_k|$ satisfying $|x_j||x_k|\leq 1$.

Comment: @mauna would you be kind enough to share the source?

Comment: @dineshdileep it is from [A first course in optimization theory](http://www.amazon.com/A-First-Course-Optimization-Theory/dp/0521497701/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1414432853&sr=8-1&keywords=a+first+course+in+optimization+theory), page 52.

Comment: @Milly I have not come across that property of unit vectors before. Can you please tell me how to prove that?

Comment: @mauna: if a vector $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ has a component $x_j$ with $|x_j|>1$, then $\|x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}\geq \sqrt{x_j^2}=|x_j|>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $C$ is the unit $\ell^2$-sphere, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality yields $$\sum\limits_{j,k=1}^n |x_j||x_k|=\left(\sum \limits_{j=1}^n |x_j|\right)^2\leqslant\left(\sum_{j=1}^n1^2\right)\cdot\left(\sum \limits_{j=1}^n |x_j|^2\right)=n.$$